# Homotopy induced on DG hom

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have question on Lemma 6.1 in https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/manetti/dispense/defosing.pdf

The setup is as follows: Suppose $\mathbb{k}$ is a field, and suppose $f,g:L\to M$ and $g,k:N\to P$ are DG $\mathbb{k}$-maps between DG $\mathbb{k}$-modules. If $f\simeq h$ and $g\simeq k$, then $f^*\simeq h^*:\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M,Y)\to\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(L,Y)$ and $g_*\simeq k_*:\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,N)\to\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(X,P)$. Where $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M,Y)$ is the DG module of all $\mathbb{k}$-maps with differential $\underline{d}(q):=[d,q]=d_Yq-(-1)^nqd_M$.

The claim that $g_*\simeq k_*$ is not difficult: In the term $\underline{d}K+K\underline{d}$ where $K$ is the homotopy, two terms with $d_X$ have different sign so they are cancelled. But this does not happen in the case of $f^*\simeq h^*$.

I'm wondering if $f^*\simeq h^*$ is true and if yes, how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got the trick. The result is still true and the homotopy should be defined slightly different as $H^*:=(-1)^n-\circ H$.